# Converge in distribution to $\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I have been hard-pressed on how to show this discrete distribution converge in distribution $e^{-x^2/2}$.

"Let $X_m$ has the discrete distribution $P(X_m \ge n) = \prod_{i=2}^n\left(1 -\cfrac{i-1}{m}\right)$. Show that $\cfrac{X_m}{\sqrt{m}}$ converges in distribution to $X \sim P(X \ge x) = 1 - \exp(-x^2/2)$."

I can see the intuition that when m is large,  $$P(X_m \ge \sqrt{m}x) = \prod_{i=1}^{x\sqrt{m}}\left(1 -\cfrac{i-1}{m}\right) \approx \exp\left(-\sum_{i=2}^{x\sqrt{m}} \frac{i-1}{m}\right) \\=\exp\left( -\frac{(x\sqrt{m} -1)(x\sqrt{m})}{2m}\right) \to \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$ as $m \to \infty$. But how to to prove properly ?

Comment: Since all points are points of continuity of the limiting distribution function, ou only have to prove your limiting equation pointwise.

Comment: $e^{-x^2/2}$ is not a probability distribution, since its integral over the real line does not equal $1$. Please clarify the meaning of *converge in distribution $e^{-x^2/2}$.*

Answer (score 1):

Using the following estimate
$$|\log(1+x)-x|=\Bigl|\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t}-x\Bigr|
=\Bigl|\int_0^x\frac{t}{1+t}dt\Bigr|\le\frac{x^2}4,\quad \text{as} \quad |x|\le \frac12, $$
it is easy to get
$$\biggl|\sum_{i=1}^{x\sqrt{m}}\log\Bigl(1-\frac{i-1}m\Bigr)-\sum_{i=1}^{x\sqrt{m}}\Bigl(-\frac{i-1}{m}\Bigr)\biggr|\le \frac14\sum_{i=1}^{x\sqrt{m}}\frac{(i-1)^2}{m^2}\le \frac{x^3}{12\sqrt{m}},\quad 
\text{as} \quad m>2x^2.
$$
Therefor, we have 
$$ \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{x\sqrt{m}}\log\Bigl(1-\frac{i-1}m\Bigr)
=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{x\sqrt{m}}\Bigl(-\frac{i-1}{m}\Bigr)=-\frac{x^2}{2}.
$$